# Rails - Secondary authentication with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, devise

I need to do a secondary authentication layer for special areas of access. So after login a user may login again after that. I'm already using Devise for normal authentication, so I can't use password field anymore and I can't use has_secure_password Rails bultin feature either.

Is there any alternative besides 100% manual way?

I made a research and found alternatives with BCrypt. But I saw it needs a password salt field. Is there any solution that doesn't need the salt field?

Comment: Can i ask why you don't want to use the salt field?

Comment: Because my user table already has a lot of fields. I will user another model with Devise as Edward suggested, it seems the best approach to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a role to your user model - option 2 here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role

If you really need 2 logins, you can have 2 entirely different devise models- see Configuring multiple models
 In the readme https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Every user will have this option, does it worth to add a role to everybody?

Comment: Adding a role is much easier than authenticating twice.

Comment: If everyone could do it, are you sure you need to even add a role or re-authenticate?

Comment: Yes, it's for checking account access. So, is it role the best aproach?

Comment: I think the second option, using multiple devise models will fit, thanks!